# ymaps API 3.0. Определение области видимости карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Предположим, что `map.bounds = [[-90, 45], [90, -45]]` и есть набор точек `const points: {coords: LngLat, data: any}[] = [/*Данные*/]`

Необходимо отфильтровать массив `points` по области видимости карты. На малых масштабах прекрасно работает правило, что `minLng <= pointLng <= maxLng` и `minLat <= pointLat <= maxLat`. Но учитывая, что по долготе карта зациклена, значение `[[-90, 45], [90, -45]]` подпадает как и под то, что в области видимости находится половина земного шара, так и под полтора. Пояснение на картинке ниже.

На картинке сверху выведены границы карты (левый-верхний угол и нижний-правый) и на карте красная линия означает левую границу, а зеленая правую. И получается, что любая пара красна+зеленая линия будет иметь границы равные выведенным. И получается так, что, чтобы правильно отфильтровать точки, нужно понимать являются ли данные границы небольшой частью карты по центру или же видно все карту.

[image: Пример неоднозначности границ]

Можно ли как-то определить, видно ли всю карту или только ее часть?

Comment: 1. Зона видимости нулевая у вас, если долгота одинаковая. 2. Широта не может быть 90 градусов на проекции Меркатора, её ограничивают областями до 80—85°. 3. Задачу опишите понятным образом, потому что получить map.location и понять попадание в границы 80-85 градусов должно быть несложно, но вы пытаетесь придумать что-то мудрёное явно.

Comment: Исправил опечатку в условии. И в апи 3.0 идет `[[lng, lat], [lng, lat]]`, сначала верхний левый, а потом нижний правый углы. `-180 <= lng <= 180`

Comment: По longlat недоглядел, виноват. Но суть вопроса всё равно непонятна – какие "половина или полтора" земного шара? Что за задача в целом решается – суть в чём? Пока выглядит, как вопрос ради вопроса, не для практического применения. Может на конкретном примере проблемы хоть опишете?

Comment: Переработал вопрос. Надеюсь так будет понятнее, что я имел ввиду

Comment: А разница в широте никак вопрос не решает? Ну условно, если широта более 80 по модулю в обоих углах карты, значит и по долготе карта вся видна. Для чего вообще эта фильтрация? Попытка сделать своё исполнение ObjectManager, что был ранее в версии 2.1? Или суть задачи в чём-то ином.

Comment: Максимальная область видимости по широте в примере просто для наглядности. Есть множество конфигурации, при которых она намного меньше 80 по модулю. Фильтрация нужна не для самой карты и это не попытка исполнения `ObjectManager`, для это есть пакет `Clusterer`. Фильтрация нужна для отображения рядом с картой списка только тех точек, которые видно в данный момент